# Can't add files after being forced to pull

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I made a ton of changes to my files and added a bunch of new files. I was able to add and commit those changes. When I tried to push I got:

```
failed to push some refs to remote.
```

After I got that, I did a `git pull`. After doing the pull I get `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master' nothing to commit, working tree clean`. Just trying to push gives me "Everything up-to-date"

The files I added and changed are not affected by the `.gitignore`. Other files of the same type were committed without a problem previously.

Comment: Would you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64616122/edit) with the full push failure message and the pull output, please? `git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline` with the relevant branches would also help.

Comment: What you are describing sounds normal. What’s the question?

Answer (score -1):

The errors may be for unrelated refs while the push succeeded for your changes.

Assuming you are working on the master branch from your question, `git log origin/master` should show your changes if this is the case.